# Invoke and define JavaScript function in same statement

Tags: javascript

Is this the correct way:

```
(function() { 
   // do something here
}());
```

Or this way:

```
(function() { 
       // do something here
    })();
```

Comment: They're both fine. I prefer the second.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's only a difference in style, both are "correct." I prefer the second and would venture that it's more popular, some prefer the first.

What you *can't* do is simply

```
function() {
    // ...this example is wrong and won't work
}();
```

You need the parentheses in order to put the parser in the right mode that you're doing a function *expression* rather than a function *declaration*, but it doesn't matter whether the invoking parens at the end are within the main parens or outside them. You can [try it with this live copy](http://jsbin.com/aquwog) with the JavaScript engines in your favorite browsers...

Comment: this is the first time I'm seeing the first type of call

Comment: @ThiagoSantos: Yeah, when I first saw it a few months back, I thought it was an error. :-) But both forms are legal and work.

Answer (score 1):

Both work, although I use the second method (and see it used more often).

Answer (score 0):

When you surround the function with parentheses, it becomes an expression (i.e. something that evaluates to a value). In other words, for the first example, its saying (evaluate me and execute me), and for the second is saying (evaluate everything in here)(and then execute me). I think the second is more intuitive because it separates what you are executing from the actual execution.

Answer (score 0):

As others pointed out, you need something before "function" to make the parser treat this as an expression, but not necessary a parenthesis. For example, Objective C fans can also use these:

```
-function() { ... } ()
+function() { ... } ()
```

Comment: That's... <del>interesting</del> gross! Objective-C fans will get confused here since it does exactly what they'd not expect.

Answer (score -2):

example :

```
function doSomething() { // The function code goes here }
```

You can click on

http://devlicio.us/blogs/sergio_pereira/archive/2009/02/09/javascript-5-ways-to-call-a-function.aspx

For More information :)

Comment: I don't understand how this answers the question?

Comment: All due respect to Bebu, but I'm having a lot of trouble seeing why anyone voted this up. It doesn't address the question at all.